# Request SE admins to allow YouTube embedding

Tags: feature-request

I've just realized that we don't support YouTube embedding. As a site that has a lot to do with **interaction**, I think we can benefit a lot from allowing video embedding. Especially since the web changes so quickly that a link to a specific online interface gets outdated very quickly, and many references are on desktop / mobile / login to begin with. We need a way to illustrate these interactions. There's a [list of SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/297500/which-sites-have-youtube-embedding-on) which do support embedding.